# How can I use `awk` to split text in column?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I extract first column (the first column  in "")

```
"xxxxx1" {685a}
"xx2" {bcdd}
"xx3 gsdd" {29a6ff}
"sdsdf xxx" {243b9}
"sdfsdf ccc dd" {c28f2f}
"dsdsf sfsdf" {216e}
"sdfsdfsd" {48530}
"sdfsdff" {9d2afa0n}
"sdfsdfdff sdfs" {d8681a}
"sdfsdsds sdfsdf d" {5b9b8}
"sdfsdfs sdf sdfsdf" {68e08a}
"sdfsdfsdf sdf" {107fa0}
```

what I want to have as result is this:

```
"xxxxx1"
"xx2"
"xx3 gsdd"
"sdsdf xxx"
"sdfsdf ccc dd"
"dsdsf sfsdf"
"sdfsdfsd"
"sdfsdff"
"sdfsdfdff sdfs"
"sdfsdsds sdfsdf d"
"sdfsdfs sdf sdfsdf"
"sdfsdfsdf sdf"
```

any idea?

Comment: I'd probably use `sed` for that: `sed -E 's/("[^"]*").*/\1/' file`

Comment: @steeldriver - sed, cut, perl, the op specified awk ans awk is less typing / less complicated

Comment: @bodhi.zazen a modified version of your (deleted) answer could be a good solution I think - `awk -F'"' '{print FS $2 FS}'`

Comment: @steeldriver Nice one, I gave up as muru posted a solution. Probably lots of options here with lots of scripts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `​ {` (space, brace) as the field delimiter, since you don't care about the second field:

```
$ awk -F ' {' '{print $1}' foo
"xxxxx1"
"xx2"
"xx3 gsdd"
"sdsdf xxx"
"sdfsdf ccc dd"
"dsdsf sfsdf"
"sdfsdfsd"
"sdfsdff"
"sdfsdfdff sdfs"
"sdfsdsds sdfsdf d"
"sdfsdfs sdf sdfsdf"
"sdfsdfsdf sdf"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want everything between the first and last `"` double-quote character of each line, the most simple solution would probably be this, using `grep` instead of `awk`:

```
grep -o '".*"' FILENAME
```

The `-o` switch lets `grep` output only the matching parts instead of the whole line that contains the match. The (single-quoted, to prevent shell interpretation) pattern `".*"` matches a sequence of any character (`.`) with any length (`*`), including zero, that is surrounded with double-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to muru's `awk` solution.

using `cut`:

```
cut -f 1 -d { < file.txt
```

using `grep`:

```
grep -o '".*"' file.txt
```

or

```
grep -o \".*\" file.txt
```

using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(".*").*/\1/' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -r 's/\{.*\}//' file.txt
```

or even:

```
sed 's/{.*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl with grouping `(.*)` can do it too:

```
$ perl -pe 's/"(.*)".*/"\1"/g' input.txt                                                    
"xxxxx1"
"xx2"
"xx3 gsdd"
"sdsdf xxx"
"sdfsdf ccc dd"
"dsdsf sfsdf"
"sdfsdfsd"
"sdfsdff"
"sdfsdfdff sdfs"
"sdfsdsds sdfsdf d"
"sdfsdfs sdf sdfsdf"
"sdfsdfsdf sdf"
```

The trick here is that we match whole line, and use `"(.*)"` to treat everything between double quotes as one group. We replace that whole line with the group we matched by referring to it via `\1` part.